# Adding UIButtons dynamically in UICollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

Trying to show buttons dynamically in a UICollectionViewCell depends on data coming in array from api. Below is what trying to achieve:

[image]

This is so far what i have achieved using button, but i need multiple buttons means button next to "About us" then next until space there then move to next line and setting height of cell as per height of view in cell. Please guide how it can be achieved.

Below is my code:

```
  var xPosition = cell.btnOptions.frame.origin.x
                var yPosition = cell.btnOptions.frame.origin.y
                var width = cell.btnOptions.frame.size.width
                var height = cell.btnOptions.frame.size.height

                if((arrOptions?.count ?? 0) > 0)
                {
                    for i in 0..<arrOptions!.count
                    {
                        //
                        cell.btnOptions.tag = i
                        cell.btnOptions.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0

 cell.btnOptions.frame = CGRect.init(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)
                       //
                        cell.btnOptions.setTitle(arrOptions?.objectAt(i).object(forKey: "title") as? String, for: .normal)
                        xPosition = width + width + 8
                        yPosition = height
                    }
```

Comment: try to use collection view in collection view cell may be its help full

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya thought that way but don't need scroll need to increase height depends on number of buttons. That's why want to choose other way

Comment: you can also manage collection view height based on your button width and height

Comment: Can you guide how, any idea